# DirectX 11 E_INVALIDARG during device creation

Tags: c++, windows, directx

The code for the creation of the d3d11 device and swapchain fails to run on some computers and returns an E_INVALIDARG error.
This also differs for computers with the same version of DirectX.
I don't seem to find the reason for the different behaviours.

```
DXGI_MODE_DESC bufferDesc;
ZeroMemory(&bufferDesc, sizeof(DXGI_MODE_DESC));
bufferDesc.Width = width;
bufferDesc.Height = height;
bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
bufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
bufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
bufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));
swapChainDesc.BufferDesc = bufferDesc;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = aaCount;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = aaQuality;
swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = *hwnd; 
swapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE; 
swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

//results in E_INVALIDARG in some cases
hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
    nullptr,                        
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,       
    nullptr,                        
    NULL,
    nullptr,
    NULL,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &swapChainDesc,
    &SwapChain,                 
    &d3d11Device,               
    nullptr,
    &d3d11DevCon);              

ID3D11Texture2D* BackBuffer;
hr = SwapChain->GetBuffer( 0, __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ), (void**)(&BackBuffer) );

hr = d3d11Device->CreateRenderTargetView( BackBuffer, nullptr, &renderTargetView );
```

Comment: what are the values of `aaCount` and `aaQuality`?

Comment: Thanks very much, these were the root of my problem!

Comment: As a reminder, the first step of debugging a Direct3D problem is to (A) enable the [Direct3D debug device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) to check for errors/warning messages, and (B) to ensure you are checking all ``HRESULT`` return values for failure. Using the debug layer would've immediately identified the problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the 'Flags' argument (currently NULL) with D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG and you'll get a human readable error message in the output that tells you what's wrong.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Technically they didn't ask a question. But if they had it probably would have been "How do I work out why this function is returning the error that it is?" to which my answer would have been as stated.

Comment: Currently sitting here in the LQF queue and I'm voting to leave this here. It instructs the OP how to enable debugging to solve their problem. I see this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the high setting for the antialiasing (aaCount, aaQuality), some systems couldn't handle them and therefore failed to create the D3D11Device/Swapchain.

Comment: This is something that the Debug layer would warn you about with an error message as follows:  
"D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D: SampleDesc.Quality specifies invalid value 0. For 16 samples, the current graphics implementation only supports SampleDesc.Quality less than 0. <-- if 0 is shown here for Quality, this means the graphics implementation doesn't support 16 samples at all."

Answer (score 0):

As discovered from comments, the reason for the device creation failure was an unsupported combination of multisample quality and/or count. This support can be queried after device creation, and before swapchain creation by using the [`D3D11CreateDevice`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476082(v=vs.85).aspx) function, and then [`ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Afterwards, a swap chain can be created with appropriate parameters.

Also, there is some guaranteed MSAA support based on the feature level, thus, if you require a certain feature level when creating the device, it can also be a way to validate the MSAA parameters (eg. and still using the `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` function). From the CheckMultisampleQualityLevels documentation, this guaranteed support is:

> Note that FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1 devices are required to support 4x MSAA for all render targets except R32G32B32A32 and R32G32B32. FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 devices are required to support 4x MSAA for all render target formats, and 8x MSAA for all render target formats except R32G32B32A32 formats.

Comment: Readers should also be aware that there are different approaches for how to expose MSAA quality levels between the various card vendors. See [DirectX 11 Hardware Vendor Differences](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/06/10/directx-11-hardware-vendor-differences.aspx)

Comment: The MSAA requirements by feature level are covered in the DXGI documentation. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and follow the links for *Related Topics*.. You may find exploring the Windows 8.x SDK ``dxcapsviewer`` tool useful as well as a way to visualize the feature level support.